# Poor performance when joining SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have a table -

```
TABLE Entries(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    [Timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL CLUSTERED INDEX,
    [PersonId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [datetime] NULL,
    [NewEntryReference] [uniqueidentifier] NULL 

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Entries_Entries] FOREIGN KEY([NewEntryReference]) REFERENCES [Entries] ([Id]))
```

and a view **EntryPerformanceView** based on that table, that calculates some values, like the current duration between Entries for a Person. When querying the view, it has no performance issues.

When I query the view and join the view on itself, based on the NewEntryReference foreign key -

```
SELECT *
FROM [EntryPerformanceView] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN [EntryPerformanceView] AS [e0] ON e.NewEntryReference IS NOT NULL AND [e].[NewEntryReference] = [e0].[Id]
WHERE [e].[PersonId] = @personId AND [e].[Timestamp] >= @fromdate AND [e].[Timestamp] < @todate
```

The query takes a very long amount of time.

Changing the joining table from [EntryPerformanceView] to [Entries] (as below) then executes in milliseconds.

```
SELECT *
FROM [EntryPerformanceView] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN [Entries] AS [e0] ON e.NewEntryReference IS NOT NULL AND [e].[NewEntryReference] = [e0].[Id]
WHERE [e].[PersonId] = @personId AND [e].[Timestamp] >= @fromdate AND [e].[Timestamp] < @todate
```

99% of the values in the NewEntryReference column are NULL and shouldn't have anything to join on

How can I fix the performance of this query while keeping the join on the view?

Edit - Execution plans

slow execution with joining view https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1ItlMoyq

fast execution with joining original table https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B16llziJc

Comment: Performance related questions require the execution plan - try Paste The Plan.

Comment: And you won't need `e.NewEntryReference IS NOT NULL`  because `[e].[NewEntryReference] = [e0].[Id]` will never match on `NULL`. One assumes you have an index on `Id`? And `NewEntryReference`?

Comment: Paste the Plan, please. `NewEntryReference` doesn't have an index to help with the join condition. A filtered index excluding `null` values would help considerably.

Comment: Also show the query that executes fast, it won't be the join, but the filter criteria that makes the other query fast

Comment: Edited question to add extra details

Comment: That view is clearly a behemoth. There are index scans and key lookups and residual filters all over. There is a huge amount of indexing and rewriting that would need doing to make it performant, but I think whatever you do you will have problems. There are just too many tables and self-joins going on. Perhaps you should cut down the amount of columns you are returning, is `SELECT *` really necessary?

Comment: The view does a lot of work, but querying this view by itself, it's performance is more than adequate. In the application, if any entry is modified or deleted, the old entry then points to the new entry as a means of tracking changes. The issue is that even if I select just a few rows that do not have any NewEntryReference pointers to new records, as in there is nothing to join, the query takes minutes to run.

Comment: Do you need to use the view? While its tempting to attempt as much reusability as possible, its not something SQL is good at. Why not build a custom query from scratch to get what you need here?

Answer (score -1):

It is very hard to answer this question without knowing how the view is defined, but here are a few hints:

- When you look at the two query plans, you will find that the slow one has a table spool and a sort operator. Bad query performance is not always a CPU or IO thing, it can also be related to queries suddenly requesting more temp space. The slow query plan also shows wait stats, where the fast one doesn't.

```
<WaitStats>
  <Wait WaitType="RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="13" WaitCount="17015" />
  <Wait WaitType="MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="470" WaitCount="581216" />
  <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="505" WaitCount="9299" />
</WaitStats>
```

- Yes, these wait times total up to around 1000ms, but from one of Brent Ozar's posts we know that these stats are not always right and do not include all the wait stats.
- The slow query plan is much longer (of course, because it contains a whole view), which leaves more room for error in the query engine. E.g. bad estimates, bad join types.

Comment: Added reference to wait times. If you downvote a post, at least write why you did so ...